# Java Reflection make final method non final

Tags: java, android, reflection

I know the way to make a `Field` non-final via Reflection. But is there a way to make a method non-final? Somehow the same approach does not work.

```
// make all methods non-final

    Clazz.javaClass.declaredMethods.forEach { method ->
        method.isAccessible = true
        val modifiersField = method.javaClass.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
        modifiersField.isAccessible = true
        modifiersField.setInt(method, modifiersField.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())
    }
```

Comment: Even if it were possible, what do you think that would help?

Comment: Does that mean its not possible?

Comment: @martynmlostekk It is useless, unless you plan on creating a new class at runtime and load that class.

Comment: @Turing85  Well, let me decide if its useful or not (_and yes, I am creating a copy of that class in runtime with modified accessibility_). Possible or not, thats the question.

Comment: @martynmlostekk in this case, you may want to include this information in your question to avoid the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible because reflection just read the compiled program, which can't be modified at runtime, because Java is a compiled language, not a scripting language.

You can, however, dynamically generate and load classes, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4093352/8154765).